# Hi does anybody know the model ? Thanks

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

Hi does anyone know which model this bike is ? Thanks

Comment: I'll note that ["Eibach"](https://eibach.com/us/p-13-about-us.html) is a car parts brand, and the label on the bike is likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

2009-ish Specialized Langster seems to be a good fit (with the bits of the bike we can see in your photo.)

Wheels likely not original.

Comment: Thank you so much and stay safe 

Comment: @HanifKhusal Instead of commenting, you can mark one answer as "accepted" because you're the Original Poster (or OP)